# Dictionary vs. hashtable

Tags: dictionary, hashtable

Can someone explain the difference between dictionaries and hashtables? In Java, I've read that dictionaries are a superset of hashtables, but I always thought it was the other way around. Other languages seem to treat the two as the same. When should one be used over the other, and what's the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Oxford Dictionary of Computing [defines a ***dictionary***](http://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/acref/9780199234004.001.0001/acref-9780199234004-e-1395?rskey=8rLbFa&result=1521) as...

> Any data structure representing a set of elements that can support the insertion and deletion of elements as well as a test for membership.

As such, dictionaries are an abstract idea that can be reasonably efficiently implemented as e.g. binary trees or hash tables, tries, or even direct array indexing if the keys are numeric and not too sparse.  That said, python uses a closed-hashing hash table for its `dict` implementation, and C# seems to use some kind of hash table  too (hence the need for a separate [`SortedDictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) type).

A [hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) is a much more specific and concrete data structures: there are several implementations options ([closed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_addressing) vs. [open](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Hash_table&redirect=no#Separate_chaining) hashing being perhaps the most fundamental), but they're all characterised by O(1) amortised insertion, lookup and deletion, and there's no excuse for begin->end iteration worse than O(n + #buckets), while implementations may achieve better (e.g. GCC's C++ library has O(n) container iteration.  The implementations necessarily depend on a hash function leading to an indexed probe in an array.

Answer (score 1):

The way i see it, a hashtable is one way of implementing a dictionary. specifying that the key is hashfunction(x) and the value is any Object. The Java Dictionary can use any key as long as .equals(y) has been implemented for that object.

The 'answer' will also change depending on the language (C#? Java? JS?) you're using. in JS the 'dictionary' is implemented as a hashtable and there is no difference. ---- in another language (i believe it's C#), the Dictionary MUST be strongly typed fixed type key and fixed type value, while the Hashtable's value can be any type, and the two are not extended from one another.